# Missing emojis from iPhone English keyboard on iOS 9.3.1

Tags: keyboard

How do I restore missing emojis to the English keyboard on my iPhone 6?
They were there, and after a reset of my phone and restoring it from a computer backup, the emojis are missing. 
I tried rebooting my device and that didn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Is the Emoji keyboard present on your list in settings/general/keyboard/keybords?  If not, add it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings, then general, then keyboard, then keyboards, then add keyboards, then find "Emoji" and add it.

Edit: thanks Tom.

Comment: There is no keyboard listed for "Emoji", which is why I can't add it.What can I do to add that keyboard??

Comment: @SJCP try following this guide and tell me what happens: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202332

Answer (score -2):

From [this article](http://iphone.appleinsider.com/articles/14/05/27/ios-quick-tips-how-to-enable-and-use-the-emoji-keyboard):

> - Navigate to Settings → General → Keyboard → Keyboards
> - Tap "Add New Keyboard..."
> - Select "Emoji" from the list

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It is better to provide a descriptive answer with the reference link, instead of an external link.

Comment: This basically is the same procedure as mentioned in the other answer (and which doesn't seem to work for the OP)

Comment: You should delete this, as it makes it look like you cannot read, since it the same thing as the answer from a month ago.